# Не удаётся найти функцию внутри dll при установке хука

Tags: c++, windows, dll, hook

Необходимо установить хук на закрытие окна, итогом которого будет сообщение в консоль. За установку хука отвечает следующая функция:

```
void SetHook()
{
HMODULE dll;
if( !(dll = LoadLibrary(L"N:\\DestrHook\\Debug\\DestrHook.dll"))  )
{
     MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("DLL"), TEXT("CAN NOT FIND"), MB_ICONERROR);
     return;
}

HOOKPROC func;
if( !(func = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(dll, "CBT_DES")) )
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("FUNC"), TEXT("CAN NOT FIND"), MB_ICONERROR);
}



if ( !(_hook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_CBT, func, NULL, 0 )) )
{
    LPTSTR err = NULL;

    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM
                  |FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER
                  |FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&err, 0, NULL );

    MessageBox(NULL, err, err, MB_ICONERROR);
}
```

}

Функция, отвечающая за срабатывание, прописана в *dllmain*:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK CBT_DES(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        if (code == HCBT_DESTROYWND)
            std::cout << "Me";
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Второе условие не выполняется (функция не находится). Подскажите, в чём ошибка?

P.S.: когда функция пробует установить хук, то ошибкой выдаёт "Неверная процедура обработки", как я понимаю, это следствие "пропажи" функции?

Comment: GetProcAddress не может найти нужную функцию?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов именно, только одна непонятная вещь, если *err* и *FormatMessage* перенести под *GetProcAdress*, то на месте ошибки пишет "Операция завершена успешно"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть была в том, что функции с таким именем действительно не существует, как показал *Dependency Walker*, она экспортировалась она под именем _CBD_DES@12. Тема имён экспортируемых функций раскрыта [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062446/x64-dll-export-function-names).